# Need help in configuring Matrix IP camera in wpf application(emguCV)

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv, face-detection, ip-camera

We are working on a project and we need to configure IP camera in WPF application.Right now,in our code we are using the laptop inbuilt camera.we want to replace that camera with our **MATRIX IP** camera.Please provide possible solution for this.

Here I am copying my code of file MainWindow.xaml.cs

Thanks in advance.

```
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private Capture capture;
        private HaarCascade haarCascade;
        DispatcherTimer timer;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            capture = new Capture("http://192.192.7.113");
            haarCascade = new HaarCascade(@"haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
            timer.Start();
        }


        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image<Bgr,Byte> currentFrame = capture.QueryFrame();

            if (currentFrame != null)
            {
                Image<Gray, Byte> grayFrame = currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

                var detectedFaces = grayFrame.DetectHaarCascade(haarCascade)[0];

                foreach (var face in detectedFaces)
                    currentFrame.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(0, double.MaxValue, 0), 3);

                image1.Source = ToBitmapSource(currentFrame);
            }

        }

        [DllImport("gdi32")]
        private static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

        public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(IImage image)
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Bitmap source = image.Bitmap)
            {
                IntPtr ptr = source.GetHbitmap(); //obtain the Hbitmap

                BitmapSource bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    ptr,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

                DeleteObject(ptr); //release the HBitmap
                return bs;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest taking this out of your UI code. Doing it in code-behind is not considered "clean coding", really. Regarding configuration of an IP camera: Is it [ONVIF](https://www.onvif.org/) compliant?

Comment: Thanks for answering Fildor. Can you please elaborate more about the actual problem with the code.

Comment: Not really a problem if it's working for you. Just a "clean code" consideration about what code should be in that MainWindow class of yours. WPF encourages MVVM and MVVM encourages to have as little code in code-behind as possible. But that is not actually directly related to your question, it just hit my eye. Maybe you want to investigate a bit in that direction.

Comment: On topic: IP Cameras can have very different APIs depending on Manufacturer. So  for answers it would be good to know if you are committed to using one model of one manufacturer or if you are planning to support a variety of models of different manufacturers?

Comment: we are committed to use
SATATYA CIBR20FL36CWS -MATRIX and right now our ip camera is running with this code.